# Mailto format with variables from VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to format text for email from mailto link using vb.net code. The output only shows the variable Client Name. It will show the whole string without the sb variable included in message. When debug and see the message variable at breakpoint, it includes the stringbuilder and string together.  Is it possible to concatenate string with string builder for mailto link? My output that I see in debugging the app for the message variable is :

Client Name: 123 Printing Please complete below line items for a new service category:%0ANew Service category:%0ABusiness Development Manager Name:%0AClient Service Manager Name:%0ARevenue:%0ARevenue Start Date:%0AClient Contact name:%0AClient contact phone:%0AClient contact Email address:%0A

All that is returned to screen is 'Client Name: 123 Printing

```
 Dim sb As New StringBuilder

   Dim clientName As String = Session("ClientName")
   Dim clientID As String = Convert.ToString(Session("myCNECTID"))


    sb.Append("Client Name :" & clientName)
    sb.AppendLine()
    sb.Append("CNECT ID: " & clientID)



    Dim message As String = _
    sb.ToString + "Please complete below line items for a new service category:%0ANew Service category:%0ABusiness Development Manager Name:%0AClient Service Manager Name:%0A" _
    & "Revenue:%0ARevenue Start Date:%0AClient Contact name:%0AClient contact phone:%0AClient contact Email address:%0A"


    HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("sfEmail").ToString() + "?subject=Request to add new service opportunity in SF for CBIZsolutions&body= " & message
```

Comment: You can concatenate any strings you want, regardless of whether or not one of them comes from a `StringBuilder`.  What exactly are the values being concatenated here and what is the resulting output?  I suspect `AppendLine()` isn't going to translate to an HTML attribute value very well.

Comment: An update has been made as an edit to question. I just don't know why it will stop printing output after the variable. If I don't have the variable it prints the message completely.

Comment: Could it be the mix of `+` and `&` operators?  Try only using `&` for string concatenation and see if that works.

Comment: It works if I don't use the Client Name. If I just use CNECTID it prints the full text. CNECTID is a string with just numerals. Maybe something in the database is having an issue with the Client Name. I have used other clients and having same problem with Client Name and just using the CNECTID does work.

Comment: You have a newline (VbCrLf; 0x13 + 0x10) after the "Client Name: ..." caused by the sb.AppendLine() call.

Answer (score 0):

For UrlEncode,
Put %0D%0A instead of %0A
That's all :)